# How to change a property binding during an element creation in QML?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qml

Suppose I have a custom `CheckBox`:

```
//MyCheckBox.qml

CheckBox {
  required property QtObject proxy

  checked: proxy.value

  Binding {
    target:    proxy
    property:  "value"
    value:     checked
  }
}
```

So the checked status of the `MyCheckBox` bound to the `value` property of my object (`proxy`) **and vise-versa**, i.e. I have a two-way binding.

I am using my custom checkbox as follows:

```
//My window
Item {

  ...

  MyCheckBox {
    id:    ordinaryCheck
    proxy: ...
  }

  ...
}
```

Everything works as expected. But what if I need to invert the logic for some instance of `MyCheckBox`: *when `proxy.value` is true the checkbox is unchecked, and when `proxy.value` is false the checkbox is checked* ? But this, ofc, doesn't work as I have a binding loop here if I try to do this:

```
Item {

...

  MyCheckBox {
    id:    invertedCheck

    proxy:     ...
    checked:   !proxy.value

    Binding {
      target:    proxy.value
      property:  "value"
      value:     !checked
    }
}
```

The Qt bindings are also not an option:

```
//MyCheckBox.qml

CheckBox {
  required property QtObject proxy

  checked: proxy.value

  Component.onCompleted {
    property.value = Qt.binding(function() { return checked });
  }
}
```

I have the same *binding loop error* in this case.

So what is my option to reach the goal, how to alternate the binding at the moment of instantiation ?

## Update 1

Here is my `PropertyProxy::setValue` member function:

```
void setValue( const QVariant& v )
{
    if( v != value() )
    {
        //do some stuff
        emit valueChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Binding {` is kind of feature of qml ?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk, It's a type: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-binding.html

Comment: I'm not sure if it's valid in casting a C++ PropertyProxy to a QML QtObject.

Comment: @StephenQuan, If under "valid" one means "it compiles, runs without warnings and/or errors, and works as expected" then I would answer yes, it is. I actually couldn't find the official example of this in the Qt docs but  here are some hints: [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html) and [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlapplicationengine.html#setInitialProperties). Actually, I register the type `PropertyProxy` via the `qmlRegister...` function, so I explicitely write `required property PropertyProxy proxy`.

Comment: @StephenQuan, of course, `PropertyProxy` **is** a `QObject`.

Comment: QtObject is a QObject, PropertyProxy is a QObject, however QtObject != PropertyProxy.

Comment: @StephenQuan, I just wanted to emphasize that the `PropertyProxy` class inherits the `QObject` : )

Answer (score 0):

[REWRITE]

For a CheckBox with two-way binding enabled, I have implemented the following properties:

```
property QtObject proxy
property string property
```

So, we can implemented a getter by reading `proxy[property]` and we can implement a setter by `proxy[property] = value;`

To handle the inverted case, I added the following additional functions which you can use to map the CheckBox values to the caller:

```
property var forward: e => !e
property var reverse: e => !e
```

Here's a working demo:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        Frame {
            ColumnLayout {
                CheckBoxTwoWayBinding {
                    id: checkBox
                    text: "CheckBox"
                    proxy: mySwitch
                    property: "checked"
                }
                CheckBoxTwoWayBinding {
                    id: invertedCheckBox
                    text: "InvertedCheckBox"
                    proxy: mySwitch
                    property: "checked"
                    forward: e => !e
                    reverse: e => !e
                }
                Switch {
                    id: mySwitch
                    text: "Switch"
                }
            }
        }
        Frame {
            ColumnLayout {
                 TextFieldTwoWayBinding {
                     proxy: fahr
                     property: "text"
                     forward: f => (parseFloat(f) - 32) * 5 / 9
                     reverse: c => parseFloat(c) * 9 / 5 + 32
                 }
                 TextField {
                     id: fahr
                     text: "32"
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}

// CheckBoxTwoWayBinding.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
CheckBox {
    property QtObject proxy
    property string property: "checked"
    property var forward: null
    property var reverse: null
    checked: forward ? forward(proxy[property]) : proxy[property]
    onToggled: proxy[property] = reverse ? reverse(checked) : checked
}

// TextFieldTwoWayBinding.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
TextField {
    property QtObject proxy
    property string property: "text"
    property var forward: null
    property var reverse: null
    text: forward ? forward(proxy[property]) : proxy[property]
    onTextChanged: proxy[property] = reverse ? reverse(text) : text
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've added the update. Could you please clarify ?

Comment: @LRDPRDX I have rewritten the answer to (1) demonstrate two-way binding, (2) how to implement a mapping

Answer (score 0):

Your first version might also technically be a binding loop but is not detected as such.

You want to bind your checkbox value to your proxy value, and when the user toggles the checkbox you want to modify the proxy value.

To avoid binding loops, use specific interaction signals for each component, not generic onChanged signal. The former will fire only when the user interact with the UI, the latter will fire every time, even when the changes come from a backend change, leading to a potential binding loop.
In your case you want the [`toggled` signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-abstractbutton.html#toggled-signal):

```
//MyCheckBox.qml

CheckBox {
  required property QtObject proxy
  checked: proxy.value
  onToggled: proxy.value = checked
}
```

Note that this only works with QQC2 since they are not breaking the `checked: proxy.value` binding when the user toggles the checkbox, but still change the `checked` property value, hoping for an eventual resolution.

Comment: Actually I have my `setValue` member function to check if the set value differs from the current (got by the `value` member function) and only if it does change the value and emit the `valueChanged` signal. Should've added this into the post, sorry.